# Как вставить все значения в бд?

Tags: sqlite

Скачал базу словаря, для каждого слова свое значение freq и для нескольких слов может быть одно значение, как понять для какого слова какое должно быть значение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру есть большая база слов

Пример
Абаьданаькъан
Адыгеера
Акхтамаранаькъан
Акъиланаькъан
Албохчанаькъан
Алханчуртски
Алхастанаькъан
Аменаькъан
Америкерча
Амхьаданаькъан
Антошканаькъан
Арсанаькъан
Арсмаканаькъан

Как мне эту базу сразу вставить в таблицу со всеми значениями и какие значения для какого слова нужны?
Извиняюсь что не совсем внятно пишу, просто первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Совсем.

Comment: *как понять для какого слова какое должно быть значение?* Либо по равенству уникального индекса, либо для установления соответствия есть отдельная таблица.

Comment: В бд может быть 50000 слов но на все эти слова распределено всего 215 freq. Вот я не могу понять по какому принципу это всё распределяется и что оно означает?